# Visual Studio 2015 ignores font settings

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I recently "upgraded" to Visual Studio 2015 (from 2010). For the first few days, it has been working properly and my development flow has not been affected too much by the TFS-related changes. However, this morning I noticed that my fonts were suddenly different. I always customize my fonts because Consolas is such an ugly font, and now with 2015, there is CodeLens, which emits some useful information regarding references and such, in the source file. The problem is that CodeLens uses yet another default font (Calibri), and makes it a tiny 8pt size in very light grey. For it to be more useful, it needs to be readable.

Anyhow, my few customizations were suddenly the defaults, so I tried changing them back. No luck. My changes appear on the screen for about a second, and then revert back. I tried restarting, but no difference. I tried reverting to a saved settings file, and reverting to defaults and doing just a single font change. Nope. I also made sure that the setting for synchronizing settings across machines was off, in case it was pulling settings from somewhere else. Nope.

I know this probably sounds trivial, but this is making me crazy. I never had this issue with 2010.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to my problem is to *not* install the newly released CTP update to Visual Studio. I had been motivated to install this update because it fixed a bug that prevented "Go To Definition" from working unless your Text Editor preferences were set to replace tabs by spaces (yes, you read that correctly!). Clearly this update is not ready for prime time as it somehow breaks Font preferences.

I have also found that uninstalling the update, or going back to a Restore point, or even repairing VS is insufficient. The only clean way I could get VS working without errors was to completely uninstall, then re-install.